# Get date from core data, then fetch and display in the tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift3.2

How to display data in the tableViewCell, which i'm fetching from core data as date?
Here is my code, but it doesn't work

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// initially set the format based on your datepicker date
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss"
    
let myString = formatter.string(from: game.date! as Date)
// convert your string to date
print("str - \(myString)")
let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
print("date - \(String(describing: yourDate!))")
//then again set the date format whhich type of output you need
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"
// again convert your date to string
let myStringDate = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myStringDate
```

Date is fetching
Here is an output

> str - 2017/07/19  13:26:40
>
> date - 2017-07-19 10:26:40 +0000

An error is

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> (lldb)

Comment: No, it's different, do you see it, dude ?

Comment: Please do like this cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this in the play ground and i worked

```
let date = Date()
let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
// convert your string to date
print("str - \(myString)")
let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
print("date - \(String(describing: yourDate!))")
//then again set the date format whhich type of output you need
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"
// again convert your date to string
let myStringDate = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
print("my string = \(myString)")
```

in the console it is printing "my string" value.